# Flutter "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'position' was called on null" when sticky header is used to wrap around GirdView.builder widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to use [sticky header](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) to wrap around a GridView.builder widget, because I want to have a header follow when the user scrolls down enough the screen, but getting "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'position' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: position See also: [https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors"](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors%22). I use this same widget to wrap around a Column widget. I tried wrapping the GridView with Container, Column and other widgets. I would just get other errors. What does this error mean?

```
return _stickyHeader.render(
        headerChild: Text(''),
        content: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
          ),
          itemCount: state.avatarUrlList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (index == state.currentSelectedAvatarIndex) {
              return Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _onAvatarImageClicked(
                      state.avatarUrlList[index], index),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 4.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 60,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage(state.avatarUrlList[index]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _onAvatarImageClicked(
                      state.avatarUrlList[index], index),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage(state.avatarUrlList[index]),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      );
    }




Widget render({Widget headerChild, Widget content}) {
return StickyHeader(
  header: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: ThemeConstants.ceruleanCrayola,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    height: 50.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: headerChild,
  ),
  content: content,
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

> You can place a StickyHeader or StickyHeaderBuilder inside any scrollable content, such as: ListView, GridView, CustomScrollView, SingleChildScrollView or similar.

You may need to try put your `StickyHeader` to `SingleChildScrollView` for basic.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll try that and see

Comment: So you are saying that StickyHeader should be inside of GridView? Because that is what your original answer says. Just trying to clarify

Comment: I don't know your design. You should put your template design to your question.